# why insert empty value using pyodbc in Linux environment?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc

FreeTDS-unixODBC-MSSQL2012

below conf :

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS Driver
Driver = /usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so.2
FileUsage = 1
CPTimeout = 5
CRReuse = 5
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
[MSSQLTEST]
driver=FreeTDS
server=10.10.1.16
port=1433
database=ACCOUNT
client_charset = UTF-8
tds_version = 8.0
```

/etc/freetds.conf

```
[MSSQLTEST]
host = 10.10.1.16
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
```

And I use pyodbc to connect MSSQL2012

```
import sys 
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

import pyodbc
conn =  pyodbc.connect("DSN=MSSQLTEST;UID=sa;PWD=xxxxx;database=PAYON;CHARSET=UTF8")
cursor = conn.cursor()
self.cursor.execute("{call insert_name('안녕')}")
```

result : name column in MSSQL2012 is empty value NOT WRONG value.

```
self.cursor.execute("{call insert_name('123')}")
```

result : name column in MSSQL2012 is 123.

name is nvarchar(50). I think that it is charset/encoding problem.

Linux is cenos6.5 and $LANG is ko_KR.UTF-8.

But I do not know the problem point.

### Additional Information

encoding problem? mssql setting?

I write code below:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MSSQLTEST;UID=sa;PWD=xxxxx;database=PAYON")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("insert into tpayon_test (name) values(N'안녕')")
cursor.commit()
conn.close()
```

and unixODBC LOG:

```
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.359552][__handles.c][450]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
        Environment = 0x1987c70
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.359682][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][182]
    Entry:            
        Environment = 0x1987c70            
        Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION            
        Value = 0x3            
        StrLen = 4
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.359740][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][349]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.359792][SQLAllocHandle.c][364]
    Entry:
        Handle Type = 2
        Input Handle = 0x1987c70
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.359865][SQLAllocHandle.c][482]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
        Output Handle = 0x19848f0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.359930][SQLDriverConnectW.c][286]
    Entry:            
        Connection = 0x19848f0            
        Window Hdl = (nil)            
        Str In = [DSN=MSSQLTEST;UID=sa;PWD=xxxxx;database=PAYON][length = 51]            
        Str Out = (nil)            
        Str Out Max = 0            
        Str Out Ptr = (nil)            
        Completion = 0
    UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ISO8859-1' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'

[ODBC][28783][1414141316.368017][SQLDriverConnectW.c][842]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                    
        Connection Out [[NULL]]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.368172][SQLSetConnectAttr.c][321]
    Entry:            
        Connection = 0x19848f0            
        Attribute = SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT            
        Value = (nil)            
        StrLen = -5
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.368872][SQLSetConnectAttr.c][675]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.368977][SQLGetInfo.c][546]
    Entry:            
        Connection = 0x19848f0            
        Info Type = SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER (77)            
        Info Value = 0x7fffe24b61c0            
        Buffer Length = 20            
        StrLen = 0x7fffe24b61be
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.369032][SQLGetInfo.c][608]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.369121][SQLGetInfo.c][546]
    Entry:            
        Connection = 0x19848f0            
        Info Type = SQL_DESCRIBE_PARAMETER (10002)            
        Info Value = 0x7fffe24b61a0            
        Buffer Length = 2            
        StrLen = 0x7fffe24b61be
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.369204][SQLGetInfo.c][608]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.369255][SQLGetInfo.c][546]
    Entry:            
        Connection = 0x19848f0            
        Info Type = SQL_NEED_LONG_DATA_LEN (111)            
        Info Value = 0x7fffe24b61a0            
        Buffer Length = 2            
        StrLen = 0x7fffe24b61be
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.369304][SQLGetInfo.c][608]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.369347][SQLAllocHandle.c][529]
    Entry:
        Handle Type = 3
        Input Handle = 0x19848f0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.369411][SQLAllocHandle.c][1064]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
        Output Handle = 0x19db6d0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.369463][SQLGetTypeInfo.c][164]
    Entry:            
        Statement = 0x19db6d0            
        Data Type = SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.391748][SQLGetTypeInfo.c][314]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.391810][SQLFetch.c][158]
    Entry:            
        Statement = 0x19db6d0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.391864][SQLFetch.c][340]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.391910][SQLGetData.c][233]
    Entry:            
        Statement = 0x19db6d0            
        Column Number = 3            
        Target Type = 4 SQL_INTEGER            
        Buffer Length = 4            
        Target Value = 0x7fffe24b61b8            
        StrLen Or Ind = (nil)
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.391970][SQLGetData.c][497]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                
        Buffer = [23]                
        Strlen Or Ind = NULLPTR
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392015][SQLGetTypeInfo.c][164]
    Entry:            
        Statement = 0x19db6d0            
        Data Type = SQL_VARCHAR
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392056][SQLGetTypeInfo.c][186]Error: 24000
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392109][SQLGetTypeInfo.c][164]
    Entry:            
        Statement = 0x19db6d0            
        Data Type = Unknown(-9)
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392196][SQLGetTypeInfo.c][186]Error: 24000
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392275][SQLGetTypeInfo.c][164]
    Entry:            
        Statement = 0x19db6d0            
        Data Type = SQL_BINARY
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392326][SQLGetTypeInfo.c][186]Error: 24000
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392386][SQLFreeStmt.c][140]
    Entry:            
        Statement = 0x19db6d0            
        Option = 0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392542][SQLFreeStmt.c][246]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392610][SQLAllocHandle.c][529]
    Entry:
        Handle Type = 3
        Input Handle = 0x19848f0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392665][SQLAllocHandle.c][1064]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
        Output Handle = 0x1a057f0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392722][SQLFreeStmt.c][140]
    Entry:            
        Statement = 0x1a057f0            
        Option = 0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392767][SQLFreeStmt.c][246]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.392814][SQLExecDirect.c][236]
    Entry:            
        Statement = 0x1a057f0            
        SQL = [insert into tpayon_test (name) values(N'안녕')][length = 48 (SQL_NTS)]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.394015][SQLExecDirect.c][499]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.394075][SQLRowCount.c][169]
    Entry:            
        Statement = 0x1a057f0            
        Row Count = 0x7fffe24b6300
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.394122][SQLRowCount.c][240]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                
        Row Count = 0x7fffe24b6300 -> 1
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.394169][SQLNumResultCols.c][152]
    Entry:            
        Statement = 0x1a057f0            
        Column Count = 0x7fffe24b631e
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.394214][SQLNumResultCols.c][244]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                
        Count = 0x7fffe24b631e -> 0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.394265][SQLEndTran.c][318]
    Entry:            
        Connection = 0x19848f0            
        Completion Type = 0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.394971][SQLGetInfo.c][546]
    Entry:            
        Connection = 0x19848f0            
        Info Type = SQL_CURSOR_COMMIT_BEHAVIOR (23)            
        Info Value = 0x1985d60            
        Buffer Length = 2            
        StrLen = 0x7fffe24b621e
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.395160][SQLGetInfo.c][608]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.395211][SQLGetInfo.c][546]
    Entry:            
        Connection = 0x19848f0            
        Info Type = SQL_CURSOR_ROLLBACK_BEHAVIOR (24)            
        Info Value = 0x1985d62            
        Buffer Length = 2            
        StrLen = 0x7fffe24b621e
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.395260][SQLGetInfo.c][608]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.395302][SQLEndTran.c][504]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.395349][SQLEndTran.c][318]
    Entry:            
        Connection = 0x19848f0            
        Completion Type = 1
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.408656][SQLEndTran.c][504]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.408716][SQLDisconnect.c][204]
    Entry:            
        Connection = 0x19848f0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.408893][SQLDisconnect.c][341]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.409055][SQLFreeHandle.c][279]
    Entry:
        Handle Type = 2
        Input Handle = 0x19848f0
[ODBC][28783][1414141316.409117][SQLFreeHandle.c][330]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
```

Comment: Try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as the first line of your Python script and using the `N` prefix for Unicode strings in SQL Server `{call insert_name(N'안녕')}`

Comment: Try `cursor.execute(u"insert into tpayon_test (name) values (N'안녕')")`. That works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing with pyodbc and FreeTDS on my Xububtu 14.04 box and found that my code worked correctly if I used a parameterized query, but it did not work with a literal query. That is, with the same FreeTDS/ODBC configuration as yours, this approach failed (inserted different characters):

```python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MSSQLTEST;UID=sa;PWD=whatever;database=myDb")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(u"insert into tpayon_test (name) values (N'안녕')")

cursor.commit()
conn.close()
```

while this approach worked fine:

```python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MSSQLTEST;UID=sa;PWD=whatever;database=myDb")
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "insert into tpayon_test (name) values (?)"
parameters = [u"안녕"]
cursor.execute(sql, parameters)

cursor.commit()
conn.close()
```

Similarly, this (and variations thereof) did not work

```python
cursor.execute(u"{call insert_name(N'안녕')}")
```

but this did:

```python
sql = "{call insert_name(?)}"
parameters = [u"안녕"]
cursor.execute(sql, parameters)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a whirl?

```
name_to_insert = '안녕'
name_to_insert.encode('utf-8')
self.cursor.execute("{call insert_name(N'" + name_to_insert + "')}")
```

Hopefully that does the trick - or you can set a header as described above, but I prefer to be explicit within the code.

Comment: I write unixODBC log below my answer. Correctly represent in unixODBC.

Comment: @SeonyHyunAhn Instead of posting your additional information as an "answer" you should have edited your question. (I have done that for you this time.)